# Send email with auto / dynamically generated PDF as attachment in PHP

Tags: php, email, pdf, attachment

I'm trying to send an email with an auto / dynamically generated PDF as an attachment in PHP. I am trying to achieve this with the code below, but it doesn't work.

```php
    <?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        //$this->Image('logo.jpg',10,6,30);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(60,10,'Convert HTML TO PDF',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Name : ',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Email : ',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Mobile : ',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Comment : ',0,1);
$pdf->Output("filename.pdf","F");
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
//$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

$email_to      = "xxx@gmail.com"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from    = "xxx@outlook.com"; // The email you are sending from (example)
$email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt     = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
$fileatt_type  = "application/pdf"; // File Type
$fileatt_name  = "filename.pdf"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers       = "From: NameHere"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message.= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" ."--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" ." name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .$data . "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
;

if(mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers))
{
    echo "File Sent Successfully.";
    //unlink($attachment); // delete a file after attachment sent.
}
else
{
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
    echo "File Not Sent .";
}
}

?>
```

Is there any mistake in my method?

Comment: have you noted theres syntax error in that example code as well. Also, echoing after die() won't do any good.

Comment: Would you show us the code where you save/write the PDF file?  The first thing to check is whether the file is being successfully created.  If we can confirm the file is being written properly, then the question becomes whether the email is attaching it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for attachment in PHP

```
//send mail .....Function calling

mail_attachment($pdf_filename,$path, $email_to,$from_mail ,$from_name, "$replyto", $email_subject ,$msg);

//delete Generated PDF  File  
unlink($file_nm); 

function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message1) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $typ=explode(".",$filename);
    $get_type=end($typ);

    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";         
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

    $message = "--".$uid."\r\n"; 
    $message.= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-type:image/jpeg; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $message  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $message1."\r\n\r\n";
    $message  .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type:  application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";  
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--".$uid."--";

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "your Mail sent.. " ;/
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear John the pdf created online and I tested it but when I try to send it there is error in sending. The code where I think error is:

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
//$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

$email_to      = "xxx@gmail.com"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from    = "xxx@outlook.com"; // The email you are sending from (example)
$email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt     = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
$fileatt_type  = "application/pdf"; // File Type
$fileatt_name  = "filename.pdf"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers       = "From: NameHere"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message.= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" ."--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" ."Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" ." name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .$data . "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
;

if(mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers))
{
    echo "File Sent Successfully.";
    //unlink($attachment); // delete a file after attachment sent.
}
else
```